# Is Rest API with OAuth2 available for Evernote Business?

Tags: evernote

I am doing integration for Evernote Business. So, I would like to know that is Evernote for Business support Rest API with OAuth2?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Evernote does not provide an official REST API; their API is Thrift-based.   If you're interested in why it's Thrift-based and not REST, their former CTO [discusses the reasons for that decision](http://blog.evernote.com/tech/2011/05/26/evernote-and-thrift/) on their tech blog.

Tadaya Tsuyukubo has written a REST-based front end for the official Evernote API which is [available here on GitHub](https://github.com/ttddyy/evernote-rest-webapp). I haven't tried it so can't personally vouch for it.  There's also a bit of discussion about it [here on the Evernote discussion forum](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/51877-webapp-to-provide-rest-api-for-evernote/).